# Чи логічно перекласти "callback" (функція зворотного виклику) словом "відклик"?

Tags: переклад, одним-словом

У програмуванні є поняття [функції зворотного виклику](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)), тобто такої функції, яку інша функція може викликати пізніше у відповідь на те, що її викликали.

Ми вже маємо переклад подібного слова *feedback* - *відгук*, тож можна пошукати слово, яке починалось би на *від-* і підходило значеннєво. Мені здається, що слово *відклик* якраз і є таким словом, а вам?

- [Горох](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA)

  > **ві́дклик** - відповідь на чий-небудь поклик, звертання
- СУМ

  > **ВІ́ДКЛИК**, *у*, *чол*. 1. ... 2, Те саме, що відгук 2. Стулив [Чіпка] пальці, приложив до рота й завив, як пугач. ..Нігде ні одклику, ні одгомону (Панас Мирний, II, 1954, 221).

Більше варіантів перекладу можна знайти на [словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kolbek).

Answer (score 1):

Суто моя думка…

По-моєму, це можливий варіант — ***функція відклику***. Можливо, створити якийсь прикметник, наприклад, ***відкликальна/відклична** функція*.

Також можна ***функція відгуку*** чи якийсь прикметник від слова *відгук*. Адже *callback* є частковим випадков *feedback*'у: *feedback* — це коли, у відповідь на щось, щось відбувається; *callback* — це коли у відповідь на *call* відбувається зворотний *call*.

Якщо порівнювати *функцію відклику* й *функцію відгуку*:

- *функція відклику* має ту перевагу, що (якщо трактувати *відгук* як *feedback* у сенсі, описаному вище, а *відклик* як *callback* у сенсі, описаному вище) це точніший термін за *функцію відгуку*;
- *функція відклику* має той недолік, що слово *[відкликати](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12744&page=420)* має також значення *скасовувати* (наприклад, *відкли́кати повноваження*); зокрема, наприклад, у [статті «Відкликання або заміна надісланого повідомлення електронної пошти» від Microsoft](https://support.office.com/uk-ua/article/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B8-35027f88-d655-4554-b4f8-6c0729a723a0) під «функцією відкликання» мається на увазі можливість знищення вже відправленого повідомлення. Коротко кажучи, читач може подумати, що «відклик(ання)» — це від *відкликати*, а не від *[відкликатися](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12745&page=420)*.

Answer (score 0):

#### Словники

> [Callback](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/callback)
>
> - a request for someone to return to a place, especially for a job interview.
> - a phone call a person makes to someone who has called them earlier.
> - a request by a manufacturer for a product to be returned because something is wrong with it.
> - a request by a company for an employee who has lost their job with the company to return to work.
> - a request by an employer for an employee to return to work after their usual working hours, especially to deal with an emergency.

Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005.

> Кликати
>
> 1. Голосом, жестом просити наблизитися, підійти, обізватися; гукати, волати.
> 2. Запрошувати когось прийти, з’явитися куди-небудь з певною метою. Бажати комусь чого-небудь, накликати якесь нещастя. Вабити, притягати.
> 3. Пропонувати діяти в певному напрямі; закликати.
> 4. Те саме, що називати.
>
> ГукАти
>
> 1. Голосно вимовляти, виголошувати які-небудь слова, звуки. Голосно кликати кого-небудь. Голосним викрикуванням пропонувати комусь
>      що-небудь, запрошувати когось куди-небудь та інше.
> 2. Голосно лаяти кого-небудь, кричати на кого-небудь.
>
> ГУкати
>
> Видавати сильні, різки звуки, шуми та інше.
>
> Відгук
>
> 1. Відбиття звуку; луна, відгомін.
> 2. Відповідь на чий-небудь поклик, звертання.
> 3. Душевний стан або дія, що є відповіддю на що-небудь.
> 4. Те, у чому виявляються сліди впливу чого-небудь; відбиття, наслідок чого-небудь.
> 5. Критична стаття, відгук та інше зумовлені появою якоїсь книги, виступом громадського діяча тощо.
>
> Відклик
>
> 1. Дія за значенням відкликати.
> 2. Відклик акцій — викуп компанією своїх акцій після завчасного повідомлення їх власників. Відклик позики — виплата позики у будь-який
>      час за бажанням кредитора або боржника. Відклик товару — розпорядження
>      покупця постачальнику про відвантаження товарів на його адресу.
> 3. Те саме, що відгук 2.
>
> Відкликати
>
> 1. Кличучи, звертаючись до когось, просити відійти від кого-, чого-небудь.
> 2. Змушувати когось залишити місце призначення, припинити виконання певних обов'язків.
> 3. Повертати до попереднього стану благанням, просьбою, покликом.

#### Чи логічно перекласти “callback” (функція зворотного виклику) словом “відклик”?

Ні, не логічно, бо відклик - це "Дія за значенням відкликати". А відкликати означає щось схоже на "покликати назад". Якщо звернете увагу, то приклади де начебто використовується слово відклик як відгук, мають в собі слово одклик, а не відклик. Не хочу говорити на цю тему, але це про щось та говорить.

#### Ми вже маємо переклад подібного слова feedback - відгук, тож можна пошукати слово, яке починалось би на від- і підходило значеннєво. Мені здається, що слово відклик якраз і є таким словом, а вам?

По перше я не розумію, чому обов'язково повинен бути префікс від- у слові, яке повинно мати теж саме значення, що й callback? По друге, чому обов'язково повинно бути лише одне слово для перекладу слова callback? Основною метою перекладу повинно бути влучне за значенням слово або слова. Тобто таке слово, або слова, які правильно передають суть сказаного.

Слова feedback і callback пов'язані між собою лише спільним коренем back. Чому потрібно взагалі згадувати про feedback, коли мова йде про callback та ще й в певній галузі програмування теж не зрозумів. Нехай буде по третє.

#### А як же тоді перекласти?

По суті вже давно переклали як **функція зворотного виклику**. А якщо є бажання використати лише одне слово, щоб було коротше, то можете використати просто **зворотна**. Приблизно за таких самих обставин використано слово **callback**. Є багато прикладів коли прикметники використовуються у значення іменників, чи потрібно наводити подібні приклади?

Приклад використання скорочення: "Передати зворотну до методу пошуку найсмачніших цукерок.". Приблизно такою говіркою напишуть те саме програмісти в чаті між собою: "Передати callback до методу lookForDeliciousCandy.". Бо щоб спростити собі життя обирають одну мову для написання програми. А так як неможливо (припустимо, що неможливо) замінити основні оператори на свою мову, то це переважно англійська.

Звичайно, що більшість програмістів не дуже зрозуміє подібне речення з першого разу через небажання взагалі перекладати англійські слова або через відсутність на це часу або ж через те, що вони вважають не раціональним подібне робити.

Середовище впливає на мову.

Comment: Було б добре якби ви ще в своїй відповіді обговорили двозначність, що виникає із перекладом *feedback* у випадку перекладу *callback* як *відгук*

Comment: Чому ви вирішили, що *відклик* приходить автоматично. Людина може відкликнутись, а може ні. Див. в запитання приклад від Мирного, там відклик не прийшов.

Comment: Мені не зрозумілий передостанній абзац. Що значить *не автоматично* і *відклик* і *відгук* можуть прийти, а можуть і ні. Вони обидва можуть бути під конторлем того хто відгукується чи відкликається.

Comment: Як це не існує двозначності? feedback - це не *відгук про товар*, це просто *відгук*, він може про що завгодно чи в електричному колі.

Comment: @Yola В електричному колі є діяльності, що походять на годування (живлення, feed), тому зворотній зв'язок до живлення називають як feedback, або ж теоретично можна назвати відгуком. Ви його живете - а воно вам відгукнеться для можливого контролю живлення електричного кола.